# javascript adding code at the beginning and at the end of every function

Tags: javascript, function, logging

for logging purpose  i would like to launch a method at the beginning and at the end of every function.

```
function myFunction1(){
   //log.start() automatically
   doStaff();
   //log.stop() automatically
}
```

is there any way to do that?
Cheers

Comment: I think it really comes down to what type of logging you're looking for. If you're just wanting to log a couple things throughout your code, you can do what you have already or use `console.log(...)` if you just want to output it to the console. I did run across this which looks like something that could help you: http://log4javascript.org/docs/quickstart.html

Comment: You probably want to look into using the profiling tools in the debugger.  Not exactly what you asked for, but that's generally how you start to understand performance at a high level and then you can manually add specific timing code when you know more specifically what you want to instrument.

Comment: Definitely. You can write a custom source transform that injects code at the beginning of every `FunctionExpression` and `FunctionDeclaration`, e.g. with recast: https://github.com/benjamn/recast. However, instead of only injecting code at the end, you should also inject it before every `ReturnStatement`. This still wouldn't cover cases where the function terminates because if a thrown error (for example).